# Is the linear combination of stationary states exhaustive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

After solving the Schrodinger Equation and getting the stationary states (separable solutions), we say the the general solution of the Schrodinger Equation is just the linear combination of these separable solutions.

My question is: How do we know that it is exhaustive, i.e., covers all possible solutions for the wave function?

(If possible please also give a proof, although just an explanation is also fine.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255251/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68822/2451

Comment: [Completeness of Storm-Liouville eigenfunctions](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat606/lecture20.pdf); it should be in your book.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Spectral_theorem).